# ESPv2 with Google Cloud Functions upstream request timeout

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm having issue getting answers from a Google Coud Function going through ESPv2.
Every time I request it, I get a response 15 seconds later with a status code of 504.
My function take between 30 to 45 seconds.
In the logs the functions correctly and answer back after 35 seconds.

Is there a way to increase the timeout in ESPv2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, in the openapi-functions.yaml under the x-google-backend you should had the attribut deadline and set it to whatever value in seconds you want.

Here is the hidden documentation https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#deadline

Issue related: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/4

Comment: This should be the right answer! Thanks for following up on your own question, I ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the documentation you used to secure the endpoints of your Cloud Function’s with ESPv2, this should be possible. If you are using Cloud Run to host your [ESPv2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions), a 504 error is sent when a request exceeds its request timeout limit. The [request timeout limit](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) is a setting that specifies the time within which a response must be returned before sending a 504 response. You can change this value by going in your “Cloud Run” tab, selecting your ESPv2 service, selecting “Edit & Deploy new Revision”, scrolling down to the capacity section and setting the time in milliseconds. This is some documentation that could prove helpful when working with the topics discussed.